# Moving Files and Photos iPhone5s to/from older non-apple devices

Tags: itunes, wifi, bluetooth, iphone

I have an iPhone 5s, an old laptop running Windows XP a Tesco Hudl, and a Samsung Galaxy 3.  How can i easily move files and photos to and from the iPhone without using my limited data allowance?

The only version of iTunes I found to download will not run on Windows XP. The iPhone Bluetooth will not talk to the Samsung Bluetooth or the Hudl.

Is there a way of doing it using the Wi-Fi bearing in mind I rarely have access to a separate Wi-Fi network/router?

The phone signal is usually very poor. The USB stick that works in the Hudl, the Samsung and the laptop will not work in the iPhone even with an adaptor. I have taken to calling it the idiot phone.

Comment: I don't know much about the Galaxy 3 or the Hudl, but couldn't you use an cloud storage service like Dropbox or OneDrive to centralize all your data then pull it down using the same client for iOS (iPhone)?

Comment: That would kind of blow the "limited data allowance" part;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can get photos ***from*** the phone using Windows Photo Gallery - assuming you can still find a version that will run on XP.
***To*** the phone will require you to find an equally ageing  iTunes.

Your problem really isn't the iPhone, it's still being on a version of Windows that hasn't been supported in years.